# AutoFilter method of Range class Failed using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error, autofilter

I got this part of a code that is causing a run time error 1004. I tried looking up different cases that were solved on Stack Overflow but could not fix the issue, although I guess it is pretty simple.

Thanks in advance for your help.

```
Sub test2()

Dim snws As Worksheet: Set snws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("SN crew")

With snws
.AutoFilterMode = False
.Range("A:J").AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:=Cells(1, 18).Value

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: `.cells(1,18).value`

Comment: Tried that but unfortunately it did not solve the error.

Comment: Is the data you are filtering in a table?

Comment: Yes, it is a table which is in the range ("A1:J2050"). But this is a query that is refreshed by another part of the code, so it may become longer.

Comment: You need to use a `listobject` then not a range. `Range.autofilter` doesn't play nice with tables.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the code is not in the sheet "SN crew". Try this:

```
'this sub in a module
Public Sub setFilter(ws As Worksheet, criteria As String)
   With ws
      .AutoFilterMode = False
      .Range("A:J").AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:=criteria
   End With
End Sub


'this sub in any sheet's module you want to set filter
Private Sub callSetFilter()
   Call setFilter(Me, "your criteria here")
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. I had to work on other topics and did not have time to test out your solution. I just tried it now, but I get a "Invalid use of Me keyword".

Comment: i wrote: this sub in any sheet module. Probably you didn't copy the Private sub in the sheet you want to filter.